# Draw a PhotoGate apparatus

Tags: tikz-pgf, metapost

Is there a way to improve a schematic representation of PhotoGate apparatus? 
These instruments are widely used in Physics, so it would be interesting to get a good representation of it.

I would like to ask for a Tikz solution and, if possible, for improvements in the artistic eye.

My first code:

```
\startMPcode
path left_cell, right_cell, p, ball, texas;
numeric u,v;
u := 1cm; v:=.5cm;
picture photogate, photogate_inactive;

photogate := image (
texas := unitsquare xscaled 2v yscaled 2u shifted(4u,v);
ball := fullcircle scaled 1.5cm;
left_cell := unitsquare xscaled v yscaled u;
right_cell := left_cell shifted (2.5u, .5v);
p := (center left_cell) -- (center right_cell);
draw left_cell;
draw right_cell;
draw p dashed evenly withcolor red;
draw texas;
draw urcorner left_cell .. urcorner left_cell + (0,2v) .. urcorner right_cell + (0,1.5v) .. center texas;
draw urcorner right_cell .. center texas + (0,-.1u);
fill ball shifted (center  p + (0,3v)) withcolor red;
draw ball shifted (center  p + (0,3v));
);

photogate_inactive := image (
texas := unitsquare xscaled 2v yscaled 2u shifted(4u,v);
ball := fullcircle scaled 1.5cm;
left_cell := unitsquare xscaled v yscaled u;
right_cell := left_cell shifted (2.5u, .5v);
p := (center left_cell) -- (center right_cell);
draw left_cell;
draw right_cell;
%draw p dashed evenly withcolor red;
fill ball shifted center  p withcolor red;
draw ball shifted (center  p);
draw texas;
draw urcorner left_cell .. urcorner left_cell + (0,2v) .. urcorner right_cell + (0,1.5v) .. center texas;
draw urcorner right_cell .. center texas + (0,-.1u);
);


draw photogate;
draw photogate_inactive shifted (7cm , 0);
\stopMPcode
```

[image]

UPDATE (after Thurston suggestions)

My new code:

```
\startMPcode
numeric u,v;
u := 1cm; v:=.5cm;

vardef photogate_base (expr ative) =
path left_cell, right_cell, p, ball, texas;
texas := unitsquare xscaled 2v yscaled 2u shifted(4u,v);
ball := fullcircle scaled 1.5cm;
left_cell := unitsquare xscaled v yscaled u;
right_cell := left_cell shifted (2.5u, .5v);
p := (center left_cell) -- (center right_cell);

image 
(
 draw left_cell;
 draw right_cell;
 draw urcorner left_cell .. urcorner left_cell + (-1u,3v) .. urcorner right_cell + (0,2v) .. center texas + (0,.6u) cutafter texas;
 draw urcorner right_cell .. urcorner right_cell + (0,.001v) .. center texas cutafter texas;
if ative == 1:
 draw ball shifted (center  p + (0,2.5v));
 fill ball shifted (center  p + (0,2.5v)) withcolor red;
 draw p dashed evenly withcolor red;
else:
 fill ball shifted (center  p + (0,.5v)) withcolor red;
 draw ball shifted (center  p + (0,.5v));
fi;
 draw texas;)
enddef;


draw photogate_base(1);
draw photogate_base(0) shifted (7cm , 0);
\stopMPcode
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  It would be good if you add an image of the result so that people can see it directly.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Do you want to improve the resulting image, and if so, how? Or do you want the code to be more efficient/better organized etc? Or do you want to find other ways to do this (for example `tikz` instead of `metapost`) which might be easier?

Comment: I would like to improve the code efficiency and the artistic result. Good tikz solutions are welcome.

Comment: The most obvious improvement is to make it more maintainable by saving the drawing of the common elements of the two pictures as (say) `photogate_base` and then making the active one by drawing the base, the path and the ball; and making the inactive one by drawing the base and the ball.   Or making a single vardef with a parameter to switch between inactive and active.